Capture of 'self' with non-sendable type 'Type?' in a `@Sendable` closure
I have a warnings 'Capture of 'self' with non-sendable type 'Type?' in a @Sendable closure' for this code
func launchPairingAtCorrectStepAfter(timeout: TimeInterval) {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: connexionTimeout, repeats: false, block: { [weak self] _ in
            self?.launchPairingAtCorrectStep()
        })
    }

I have been trying to resolve it with Task{ @MainActor }

Please show an minimal reproducible example.

The approach of isolating the Task to the main actor works if the type is also actor-isolated, e.g.:
@MainActor
class Foo {
    func launchPairingAtCorrectStepAfter(timeout: TimeInterval) {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: timeout, repeats: false) { [weak self] _ in
            MainActor.assumeIsolated {
                self?.launchPairingAtCorrectStep()
            }
        }
    }

    …
}

Personally, though, I would be inclined to abandon Timer and just make this an async method that calls Task.sleep (which is a non-blocking, asynchronous sleep function):
func launchPairingAtCorrectStepAfter(timeout: TimeInterval) async throws {
    try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(timeout))
    launchPairingAtCorrectStep()
}

